# angular js directive - How to evaluate angular tags of directive's template html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive whom's behavior I want to control using attributes. It's a navbar that should should have an active item depending on the value of an attribute

```
<navbar active="programs"></navbar>
```

The directive's template

```
<div class="navbar span12">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Loopz</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('programs')}"><a href="#/programs">Programs</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('shop')}"><a href="#/shop">Shop</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('profile')}"><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `active` class should be put on the element that has the matching `active` attribute value. The template should be evaluated and the directive's internal scope should have a function that matches the `active` attribute's value with the value passed to the directive's scope method `isActive(value)`

The directive

```
directivesModule.directive('navbar', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "partials/navbar.html",
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.isActive = function(value){
                return $attrs.active === value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The `isActive` function is being called with the correct value but the `$attrs` object doesn't contain the `active` attribute's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just dropped all your code into a jsFiddle (it'd be helpful if you did it next time) and everything seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/110/

Here's the output of the li that should be active:

```
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('programs')}" class="active">
    <a href="#/programs">Programs</a>
</li>
```

Comment: The jsFiddle does indeed work. I should also mention that I'm using this directive inside a partial html that's being loaded by an ng-view. I'll try to modify the jsFiddle to mimick the setup

Comment: I figured out what was going on. The directive's controller's scope inherited from a parent scope that already had an isActive method. After renaming the method defined in the directive's scope all works as expected. I'd rather not have the directive's scope inherit the parent's scope though. The directive docs refer to 'isolate' scope, which sounds like something I should use in this case.